# Default Value Radio Button and Form Question

Tags: forms

I am new to EE and am faced with an issue on a clients site. They have two radio buttons that are in their code like this:

```
<script>
$('#shippingAdd').hide();
$("input[name=use_billing_info]:radio").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'y') {
        $('#shippingAdd').hide();
    } else {
        $('#shippingAdd').show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to set the radio button to default to 'y' being selected? How do I change this? If setting a default value is not a viable option is it possible to change this to a pulldown menu?

I'm not sure exactly how the above code works. Any feedback/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't EE related

Answer (score -1):

I mean no offense, but if you don't understand the code you pasted, you should not be the person editing your clients code. It's extremely simple jQuery stuff. I'm serious; tell your client to hire a developer. You are doing them a disservice by trying to solve issues you aren't capable of solving. I'm sorry if that comes out harsh but as professional developer, this kind of activity makes me turn away clients all the time; shoddy work always means clients not returning to your business. This is also a developers forum which is why I gave you that speech; this isn't a help center or tutorial site for self-trained devs.

All of that said, I'm still going to help you. This code should be added just before the **end** of your `<body>` tag:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // when our document is ready, set that input to 'y'
    $("input[name=use_billing_info]:radio").val('y');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Don't be so harsh. Everyone starts somewhere.

Comment: That wasn't harsh at all, it was very buffered and good advice. Is your EE-related career important to you or is this a joke? I should have flagged the question as distinctly off-topic as is, it's purely HTML and jQuery, but I still gave the questioner a solution.

Comment: @CreateSean ok yeah, that was harsh. I must have been having a bad day. I'm sorry to mpar612 for being a jerk, I hope I still helped that person.